# Uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ satisfying $f_n\left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right) = f_n(x)$ implies that the limit is a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, epsilon-delta

**I encountered this problem on a graduate school entrance test :**

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real-valued continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f_n\left(x + \frac{1}{n}\right) = f_n(x) \hspace{2mm} \forall \hspace{2mm} x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } n \in \mathbb{N}.$$ Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then show that $f$ is a constant function.

**My attempt :**

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. It suffices to show that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. By triangle inequality, given any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)|$$
By uniform convergence, $\exists$ $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon/3$ and $|f(y) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon/3 $ whenever $n > \mathbb{N}$.

So, now it suffices to show that $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \to 0$. Now comes the confusing part :

- I fix an $n$.
- Continuity of $f_n$ implies that existence of $\delta >0$ such that $|f_n(t)-f_n(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|t-y|<\delta$.
- Find $n'$ such that $\frac{1}{n'} < \delta$. Then, $\exists$ $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left|\left(x+\frac{k}{n'}\right) - y\right| < \delta$.
- But now I can't say that $|f_{n'}(x)-f_{n'}(y)| = |f_{n'}(x+\frac{k}{n'})-f_{n'}(y)| < \epsilon$ as $f_{n'}$ might require a smaller $\delta'$ than $f_n$.

I hope I have made my point clear. If not, feel free to ignore my attempt and post your own solution.

Any help/hints shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $q= a/b\in \Bbb Q,$ with $a\in\Bbb Z$ and $b\in\Bbb N,$ for any $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $$\forall j\in\Bbb Z\,(\,f_{nb}(j/nb)=f_{nb}((j+1)/nb)\,)$$  so $f_{nb}(0)=f_{nb}(a/b)=f_{nb}(q).$ Therefore  $$f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{nb}(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{nb}(q)=f(q).$$ So $f$ is constant on $\Bbb Q.$ Now $f_m\to f$ uniformly, and each $f_m$ is continuous, so $f$ is continuous. So $f$ is continuous and $f$ is constant on $\Bbb Q$ so $f$ is constant.

Comment: That is a very clever answer.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Another_Ramanujan_Fan . I just thought of a slightly more difficult generalization: Suppose each $f_n$ is continuous and periodic with period $p_n.$  If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $p_n\to 0$ then $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yess ! Brilliant.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x \in \Bbb R$ be arbitrary and let $m = m(n) \in \Bbb Z$ be such that $y := x - \frac m n \in \left[0, \frac 1 n \right)$. Observe,

$$
f_n(x) =
f_n \left(x - \frac 1 n \right) =
f_n \left(x - \frac 2 n \right) =
\dots =
f_n \left(x - \frac m n \right) =
f_n \left(y \right)
$$

Since $f_n$ continuous, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, by the [Uniform Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem) we have that $f$ is continuous.

Now, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $N \in \Bbb{N}$ large enough, such that for all $n \ge N$ we have

$$
\left|f_n(x) - f(0)\right| =\\
\left|f_n(y) - f(0)\right| =\\
\left|f_n(y) - f(y) + f(y) -f(0)\right| \le\\
\left|f_n(y) - f(y)\right| + \left|f(y) - f(0)\right| \le\\
\dfrac \epsilon 2 + \dfrac \epsilon 2 =\\
\epsilon
$$

where the bound on the first term is due to uniform convergence, and the bound on the second term is due to the continuity of $f$. Note that $\epsilon$ is a uniform bound.

Finally,

$$
|f(x) - f(0)| =
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n(x) - f(0)| \le
\epsilon
$$

Comment: +1 I don't understand why this was not the accepted answer.  It is so much clearer and simpler.

Comment: Can’t cater to everyone :-)

Comment: +1. This method can easily adapt to prove the generalization that I stated in a comment to my A.

Comment: yours was a great answer, too, @DanielWainfleet.